# Training with tensorflow is much slower using GPU rather than CPU on M1 Max

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, gpu

I tried to run the example below (a simplified version of a part of [this tutorial](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml3/blob/main/15_processing_sequences_using_rnns_and_cnns.ipynb)).
I was extremely surprised to see that for this model at least, the training was more than 50x faster on the CPU.

```
from pathlib import Path
import tensorflow as tf

tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    "ridership.tgz",
    "https://github.com/ageron/data/raw/main/ridership.tgz",
    cache_dir=".",
    extract=True
)
path = Path("datasets/ridership/CTA_-_Ridership_-_Daily_Boarding_Totals.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=["service_date"])
df = df.sort_values("service_date").set_index("service_date")
df = df.drop_duplicates()

rail_train = df["rail_boardings"]["2016-01":"2018-12"] / 1e6
rail_valid = df["rail_boardings"]["2019-01":"2019-05"] / 1e6

seq_length = 56

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    rail_train.to_numpy(),
    targets=rail_train[seq_length:],
    sequence_length=seq_length,
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42
)
valid_ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    rail_valid.to_numpy(),
    targets=rail_valid[seq_length:],
    sequence_length=seq_length,
    batch_size=32
)

tf.random.set_seed(42)  # extra code – ensures reproducibility
deep_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[None, 1]),
    tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(32, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(32),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
```

Running using the GPU is extremely slow:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9)
    deep_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(), optimizer=opt, metrics=["mae"])
    deep_model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=valid_ds, epochs=10)
```

Gives:

```
Epoch 1/10
2023-01-25 15:08:13.733000: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
33/33 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0306 - mae: 0.1614
2023-01-25 15:12:10.354167: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
33/33 [==============================] - 241s 7s/step - loss: 0.0306 - mae: 0.1614 - val_loss: 0.0045 - val_mae: 0.0783
Epoch 2/10
33/33 [==============================] - 265s 8s/step - loss: 0.0082 - mae: 0.0985 - val_loss: 0.0118 - val_mae: 0.1358
Epoch 3/10
33/33 [==============================] - 243s 7s/step - loss: 0.0066 - mae: 0.0838 - val_loss: 0.0030 - val_mae: 0.0567
Epoch 4/10
33/33 [==============================] - 236s 7s/step - loss: 0.0046 - mae: 0.0631 - val_loss: 0.0022 - val_mae: 0.0455
Epoch 5/10
17/33 [==============>...............] - ETA: 1:52 - loss: 0.0045 - mae: 0.0609
```

While using CPU:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9)
    deep_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(), optimizer=opt, metrics=["mae"])
    deep_model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=valid_ds, epochs=10)
```

We get:

```
Epoch 1/10
2023-01-25 15:35:43.883427: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
33/33 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0046 - mae: 0.0654
2023-01-25 15:35:48.833485: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
33/33 [==============================] - 7s 160ms/step - loss: 0.0046 - mae: 0.0654 - val_loss: 0.0020 - val_mae: 0.0417
Epoch 2/10
33/33 [==============================] - 4s 128ms/step - loss: 0.0049 - mae: 0.0705 - val_loss: 0.0019 - val_mae: 0.0394
Epoch 3/10
33/33 [==============================] - 4s 135ms/step - loss: 0.0043 - mae: 0.0633 - val_loss: 0.0020 - val_mae: 0.0386
Epoch 4/10
33/33 [==============================] - 4s 131ms/step - loss: 0.0036 - mae: 0.0521 - val_loss: 0.0019 - val_mae: 0.0353
Epoch 5/10
33/33 [==============================] - 4s 127ms/step - loss: 0.0038 - mae: 0.0550 - val_loss: 0.0021 - val_mae: 0.0407
Epoch 6/10
33/33 [==============================] - 4s 123ms/step - loss: 0.0037 - mae: 0.0550 - val_loss: 0.0018 - val_mae: 0.0328
Epoch 7/10
33/33 [==============================] - 4s 123ms/step - loss: 0.0041 - mae: 0.0618 - val_loss: 0.0026 - val_mae: 0.0532
Epoch 8/10
33/33 [==============================] - 5s 141ms/step - loss: 0.0037 - mae: 0.0559 - val_loss: 0.0018 - val_mae: 0.0328
Epoch 9/10
33/33 [==============================] - 4s 129ms/step - loss: 0.0037 - mae: 0.0549 - val_loss: 0.0031 - val_mae: 0.0570
Epoch 10/10
33/33 [==============================] - 4s 129ms/step - loss: 0.0036 - mae: 0.0553 - val_loss: 0.0023 - val_mae: 0.0432
```

I understand that sometimes, CPU can be faster for simple models so I also tried stacking 15 of such `tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(32, return_sequences=True)` layer, and got the same kind of ratio, if not worse.

I am using conda with the following versions of the relevant libraries:

```
tensorflow-datasets       4.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-deps           2.9.0                         0    apple
tensorflow-estimator      2.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-macos          2.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-metadata       1.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-metal          0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Comment: Did you got the right GPU driver and the cuda and cudnn files? And did you installed tensorflow-gpu?

Comment: I just followed the official installation guidelines there: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes read the "currently not supported" area at the end of the page

Comment: Do you speak about "Acceleration for Intel GPUs"? Because this is not my case since I have a M1 Max, so the GPU is from Apple, integrated in the M1 Chip. But maybe tf considers it as a CPU (but then what does it use when I specify "with tf.device('/gpu:0')" ?

Comment: Apple says that they dont support Multi-GPU support, Acceleration for Intel GPUs, V1 TensorFlow networks

Comment: Yes, but I am using one Apple GPU and Tensorflow V2, so in my understanding this is not linked with my issue.

Comment: Look at this post, maybe the batch size is the cause: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696224

Answer (score 1):

The SimpleRNN is slower in GPU but not in CPU because of it's computation way.
The SimpleRNN layer uses a recurrent neural network to process its input data in a **sequential manner** which can be inefficient on GPU because GPU's are designed to process data in parallel. They do this by using a feedback loop that allows the network to process the previous output as well as the current input. GPUs have to process the data in SimpleRNN one step at a time, which makes it slower than processing the data in parallel.

To overcome this limitation of SimpleRNN you can use a different type of recurrent neural network which are - **LSTM(Long short-term memory)** and **GRU(Gated Recurrent Unit)** network.

**LSTM** - The LSTM is faster because it is optimised for GPU computation. LSTM is a type of RNN that is more easily parallelized than SimpleRNN. LSTM has gates that control the flow of information through the network. These gates can be parallelized which allows LSTM to be faster in GPU than SimpleRNN.

**GRU** - GRUs are similar to SimpleRNNs, but they have a few features that make them faster on GPU. For example, GRUs have a reset gate that allows them to forget information from previous time steps. This can help to improve performance on GPU because it reduces the amount of data that needs to be processed.

In addition, LSTM is better at handling long-term dependencies than SimpleRNN. This is because LSTM has a memory cell that can store information over time. This allows LSTM to learn relationships between inputs that are far apart in time.

Comment: This is not correct, LSTMs are also recurrent networks, so they would suffer from the same issue as SimpleRNNs.

Comment: Yes @Dr. Snoopy, The SimpleRNN, LSTM and GRU are recurrent networks but a little different way of computations. I have reformed the answer to avoid the confusion. Thank you.